# Request Timeout due to Request Size in Azure API App

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I am facing request timeout issue with Azure API App. When the request size is fairly large (more than 120 kb). I encounter a timeout issue and the request doesn't reach the app. On disabling client auth the same request works seamlessly.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you are performing client auth?

Comment: we have enabled the certificate check from the API App Resource Group property. and performing the certificate validation and function level.

Comment: @AkbarAnsari How do I perform this certificate validation? I am using custom authentication.

Comment: @AkbarAnsari I am facing this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the App Service setting to enable clientCert. Then try calling the API to see if I get a 401 response. After that I would try adding the certificate to the request and see if I can pick it up in my API-endpoint

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth